# passing multiple secondary geometries into vertex shaders using threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

Lets say I have a geometry which I am using the vertices of to create `Points` or an `InstancedMesh`. But then I want change this underlying geometry to something else, let's as a cone to a sphere or something which has the same number of vertices. I would like to animated between these without using `MorphTargets` so I guess I need to use a custom vertex shader which is fine however I'm a bit stuck as to how to pass in the additional `BufferGeometry`s into the vertex shader.
I can't really think how I might do this with the `uniforms` - has anyone got any ideas as, in my understanding i can only use int/float/bool/vec/ivec/mat but i need multiple vertex buffers - is it just an array of some kind?

I guess i'm trying to find a way of having multiple "full" geometries which i can interrogate within the vertex shader but can't figure out how to access/pass these additional buffers into webgl from three.js

Comment: Your reason for wanting not to use `MorphTargets` is not apparent, but passing the targets into a vertex shader is precisely what `MorphTargets` do.  See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/morphtarget_vertex.glsl.js

Comment: I what to be able to have much greater control of the transitions between morph targets, i.e. only morph the x or rotation and to do it non-linearly i.e not lerping

Answer (score 0):

The default position of the vertices is defined in a [BufferAttribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute) called `position`. This is passed to the vertex shader as `attribute vec3 position`.

You could create a new BufferAttribute in your geometry called `position2` and you can define it in your vertex shader as `attribute vec3 position2`.

Comment: I guess i'm trying to find a way of having multiple "full" geometries which i can interrogate within the vertex shader but can't figure out how to access/pass these additional buffers into webgl from three.js

Comment: @Alex What you're asking is pretty complex. Do you already know how to use custom shaders? Can you show us the code you've implemented so far in Three.js and your vertex shader so others can see how far along you've gone so far?